# unable to access new method from class python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am facing a issue. When i add new method in a class, then i am unable to call it through their instance variable. Here is the details of the issue.

I am using https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot.

I have added new method in bot.py file (https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot/blob/master/instabot/bot/bot.py). Here is code of new function.

```
......
......

from .bot_stats import get_user_stats_dict

class Bot(API):
....
    def get_user_stats_dict(self, username, path=""):
        return get_user_stats_dict(self, username, path=path)
```

It is calling new function with the same name from bot_stats file(file link: https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot/blob/master/instabot/bot/bot_stats.py). Here is the function code which i have added in this file.

```
def get_user_stats_dict(self, username, path=""):
    if not username:
        username = self.username
    user_id = self.convert_to_user_id(username)
    infodict = self.get_user_info(user_id)
    if infodict:
        data_to_save = {
            "date": str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)),
            "followers": int(infodict["follower_count"]),
            "following": int(infodict["following_count"]),
            "medias": int(infodict["media_count"]),
            "user_id": user_id
        }
        return data_to_save
    return False
```

I have created a new file test.py which is running this new method. Here is the code script:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import argparse

sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], '../'))
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username='username', password='pass')
resdict = bot.get_user_stats_dict('username')
```

I am running test.py file using following command in CMD.

```
python test.py
```

I am getting following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_user_stats_dict'
```

Comment: Are you importing the Bot from the same file? I mean, are you sure that there are not two definitions of Bot in different files?

Comment: You are importing a function in that name `from .bot_stats import get_user_stats_dict`. Why? btw - if that's an instance method, you can't simply import that.

Comment: @hspandher. I already make sure this point. Yes, it is the same file. I am using the same directory structure as in the repository.

Comment: @Vinny. it is not instance method. I have defined it in a separate file and import it in class file so that i can call it from class.

Comment: You need to define it IN the class so it can be called on a class object. You can't import functions outside the class and use them like instance methods.

Comment: @Vinny.... it is in the class. But their implementation is in the separate file. The class file is bot.py.. which contains method. I am calling bot class method from test.py.

Comment: How can it be inside the class, and at the same time implemented in a different module? Also, why do you import a function and then define a method using the same name?..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have **an instance method** defined inside your class. The error you get is because your **instance object** has no bounded methods in that name. This means it has no method defined in the class, so I would double check that. (the def indent is correct; it's location is right, etc.)

I have tried the following simple example. This code works:

```
# test2.py
def other_module_func(self):
    print self.x

# test.py
from test2 import other_module_func

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def other_module_func(self):
        return other_module_func(self)

a = A(4)
a.other_module_func()
4
```

Comment: I am very new to python. If you see this file(https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot/blob/master/instabot/bot/bot.py). There are save_user_stats function. I have added my function in the same way.

Comment: I understand. I've updated my answer with a simple example, where it does work

Comment: Can i see the path location of class by their instance. like in your example. Path location of A class by using a variable?

Comment: Can you put them on the same folder? If not, you can use an ugly hack: insert the folder to the first item in `sys.path`.

Comment: Thanks @Vinny, i installed a instabot package which i have remove now and it started working.